# Help needed with UIImage manipulation

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I have two UIImage objects as follow:

image1:

[image]

image2:

[image]

I wish to combine the two images via code so I can get the following image:

[image]

My graphics skills in iPhone are really poor... so any sample code will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking at applying a **mask** to an image, [so take a look here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html), hope it helps

Comment: Great, this is really helpful. Since my image1 is more than just a mask (say, I wish special decorating the frame) how would you recommend doing that?

Comment: I'm not so skillful in images too, so I can't help you that much. What I can think of is that you add another image with the decoration, apply the mask to it too and then put it as a top layer on the other